# How do i export one JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, class, import, module, export

i have this Class that i'm trying to Export :

```
   class Lists {

     constructor(list) {

     this.list = list;

     }}

  module.exports = Lists;
```

And when i try to export the class it give me this error

```
  module.exports = Lists;


  module is not defined
```

Comment: In what context is this code running? Node, or a browser, or somewhere else?

Comment: The code is running using node

Answer (score 0):

```
// you simply need to use only the export statement

 class Lists {

 constructor(list) {

 this.list = list;

 }}

export {Lists}
```